# Difference between 超える【こえる】 and 超す【こす】？

Tags: word-choice

こんばんは、皆！(6:25pm in Russia)

So, I just got confused by these two words (超える【こえる】 and 超す【こす】). Can someone explain them to me? Do they have the same meaning, or am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right in that both verbs have roughly the same meaning. Here are the differences I could find with my (limited) knowledge of Japanese:

超える can be used when something exceeds the norm, or is out of the ordinary.

超す can be used for "moving home" (引っ超す）, whereas the above cannot (<strike>引っ超える</strike> ).

Another example is that you cannot say 年を超える、here 年を超す would be correct. 
I believe 超す is less common than 超える, in the cases where you could use either.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explaination! Now I understand the difference.

Comment: Wrong kanji. 引っ越す, not 引っ超す. 年を越す, not 年を超す.